# Pass many variables in SQL query

Tags: sql, matlab, syntax

There are 2 user inputs, `violation_type` and `vehicle`. I want to pass these variables to back-end database to make a report in Matlab. I have tried with one  variables and it works fine, but i do not know how to pass multiple variables to filter the database records according to user search.

> vehicle = 'car';
>   violation _type = 'U turn';

---

> 'SELECT lic.licence_plate_num,lic.owner_name,lic.owner_address,lic.owner_tel_no,lic.owner_email,vio.violation_date,vio.violation_time,vio.vehicle_type,vio.violation_type FROM licence_plate_details lic RIGHT JOIN violated_vehicles vio ON lic.licence_plate_num = vio.licence_plate_num where vio.vehicle_type = ''', vehicle, ''''

Answer (score 1):

Use AND keyword in your SQL query for multiple criteria. You can use [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) MATLAB function to insert variable parameters. I've also separated your query into multiple substrings for better readability.

```
sql = sprintf( [ ...
    'SELECT lic.licence_plate_num, lic.owner_name, lic.owner_address, '...
    'lic.owner_tel_no, lic.owner_email, vio.violation_date, '...
    'vio.violation_time, vio.vehicle_type, vio.violation_type '...
    'FROM licence_plate_details lic RIGHT JOIN violated_vehicles vio '...
    'ON lic.licence_plate_num = vio.licence_plate_num '...
    'WHERE vio.vehicle_type = "%s" AND vio.violation_type = "%s"' ], ...
    vehicle, violation_type );
```